# jsonapi way of tracking updated user after request on linked resource

Tags: rest, json-api

This question is based on formats from http://jsonapi.org/

Say for a feature like follow/unfollow were to be implemented, the best jsonapi way of doing this would be making the following request:

```
POST /users/<user_id>/following/
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
{
    "data": [
        { "type": "user", "id": <following_user_id> }
    ]
}
```

Now, user resource has attributes (e.g. is_followed, followers_count) that are affected by this request. My question involves coming up with a way to handle this from one of the two options.

1. Let the client know of changes in related resources through Response
2. Expect client to make GET request to refresh the resource

Answer (score 0):

The JSON API spec states the following from [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating):

> A resource can be created by sending a POST request to a URL that represents a collection of resources. The request MUST include a single resource object as primary data. The resource object MUST contain at least a type member.

So, as long as you have a type member, both of the approaches are technically correct.

The better of the two approaches is the first one and it is a common convention in most of the JSON API implementations to return all the attributes of the resource created in its response. Expecting the client to make a GET request to refresh the resource seems like bad practice.